# Using .Contains Method with Cached Hashset

Tags: .net, vb.net, hashset

I know that the .Contains method on a hashset is fast. My question is what is the best method for getting the hashset data before repetitively using the .Contains method?

I can think of 2 options. Both of these examples would be called in a loop of undetermined length.

---

1) Call the method that returns the cached hashset directly and use the .Contains method.

```
IF (GetHashSetMethod.Contains("TESTVALUE") THEN BLAH, BLAH, BLAH...
```

---

2) Create a new hashset outside of the loop and load the cached hashset data into it so the method that returns the hashset is only called once, then use the .Contains method.

```
DIM HashTest AS HASHSET(OF String) = GetHashSetMethod
```

Then in loop:

```
if (HashTest.Contains("TESTVALUE") THEN BLAH, BLAH, BLAH...
```

---

I have been using method 1. Should I even think about switching to method 2? Is there a 3rd option I haven't even thought of? Does it even matter because the data is cached to begin with?

Comment: Have you tried option 2 to see if it's faster or slower than option 1?

Comment: Actually, I have tested it out and I didn't really see any difference, but i wasn't expecting to see any major performance difference.  I'm wondering if I should be doing it that way in the first place. Is there a generally accepted best practice for this sort of thing that I don't know about or is consistency the most important thing in a case like this?

Comment: I think you are missing a pair of `()` after `GetHashSetMethod` on your first example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In matters of speed, the answer is generally to write it both ways and see if you can actually measure a difference that is meaningful.

For code clarity, I would suggest you opt for solution 2. It's going to code that will be easier to understand, maintain, and debug if all goes to pot.

Answer (score 1):

Generally if you loop you should do everything that can be done outside the loop outside the loop.

It may not result in a notable performance change because todays processors are insanely fast, and the compiler may be able to optimize the code. However it's just cleaner in my opinion. The code inside the loop concentrates about it's own purpose and does not have to execute "setup" code on every step.

An other consideration is changing code. If your todays `GetHashSetMethod` just returns a reference to a singleton you won't experience any difference in speed. However as soon someone changes it to (for example) load the hash sets data from a file you got a problem if you get your `HashSet` n-times.